# Optimize summing 2 arrays of bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, opencv

I am iterating through an array of bytes and add values of another array of bytes in a for loop.

```
        var random = new Random();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[20_000_000]; 
        byte[] bytes2 = new byte[20_000_000];

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)random.Next(255);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes2[i] = (byte)random.Next(255);
        }

        //how to optimize the part below
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] += bytes2[i];
        }
```

Is there any way to speed up the process, so it can be faster than linear.

Comment: Are you asking to concatenate two byte arrays, or add each element of a byte array?

Comment: @juharr Added code.

Comment: @CoryNelson Add each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Vector`:

```
static void Add(Span<byte> dst, ReadOnlySpan<byte> src)
{
    Span<Vector<byte>> dstVec = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, Vector<byte>>(dst);
    ReadOnlySpan<Vector<byte>> srcVec = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, Vector<byte>>(src);

    for (int i = 0; i < dstVec.Length; ++i)
    {
        dstVec[i] += srcVec[i];
    }

    for (int i = dstVec.Length * Vector<byte>.Count; i < dst.Length; ++i)
    {
        dst[i] += src[i];
    }
}
```

Will go even faster if you use a pointer here to align one of your arrays.

Comment: Wanted to point out this requires .NET Core >= 2.1 or .NET Standard >= 2.1.  MemoryMarshal is not available on .NET Framework.

Comment: It gives 5X boost !

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize all your processors/cores, assuming that your machine has more than one.

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, bytes.Length), range =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] += bytes2[i];
    }
});
```

---

**Update:** The [`Vector<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1) class can also be used in .NET Framework. It requires the package [System.Numerics.Vectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors). It offers the advantage of parallelization in a single core, by issuing a Single Instruction to Multiple Data ([SIMD](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-jit-finally-proposed-jit-and-simd-are-getting-married/)). Most current processors are SIMD-enabled. It is only enabled for 64-bit processes, so the flag [Prefer 32-bit] must be unchecked. On 32-bit processes the property [`Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector.ishardwareaccelerated) returns `false`, and the performance is bad.

```
using System.Numerics;

/// <summary>Adds each pair of elements in two arrays, and replaces the
/// left array element with the result.</summary>
public static void Add_UsingVector(byte[] left, byte[] right, int start, int length)
{
    int i = start;
    int step = Vector<byte>.Count; // the step is 16
    int end = start + length - step + 1;
    for (; i < end; i += step)
    {
        // Vectorize 16 bytes from each array
        var vector1 = new Vector<byte>(left, i);
        var vector2 = new Vector<byte>(right, i);
        vector1 += vector2; // Vector arithmetic is unchecked only
        vector1.CopyTo(left, i);
    }
    for (; i < start + length; i++) // Process the last few elements
    {
        unchecked { left[i] += right[i]; }
    }
}
```

This runs 4-5 times faster than a simple loop, without utilizing more than one thread (25% CPU consumption in a 4-core PC).

Comment: I updated my answer with info about using the [`Vector<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1) class in .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2):

Pad the array length to the next highest multiple of 8.(It already is in your example.)

Use an unsafe context to create two `ulong` arrays pointing to the start of the existing byte arrays.  Use a `for` loop to iterate `bytes.Length / 8` times adding 8 bytes at a time.

On my system this runs for less than 13 milliseconds. Compared to 105 milliseconds for the original code.

You must add the `/unsafe` option to use this code. Open the project properties and select "allow unsafe code".

```
var random = new Random();
byte[] bytes = new byte[20_000_000]; 
byte[] bytes2 = new byte[20_000_000];




int Len = bytes.Length >> 3; // >>3 is the same as / 8

ulong MASK =    0x8080808080808080;
ulong MASKINV = 0x7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f;

//Sanity check
if((bytes.Length & 7) != 0) throw new Exception("bytes.Length is not a multiple of 8");
if((bytes2.Length & 7) != 0) throw new Exception("bytes2.Length is not a multiple of 8");

unsafe
{
    //Add 8 bytes at a time, taking into account overflow between bytes
   fixed (byte* pbBytes = &bytes[0])
   fixed (byte* pbBytes2 = &bytes2[0])
   {
      ulong* pBytes = (ulong*)pbBytes;
      ulong* pBytes2 = (ulong*)pbBytes2;
      for (int i = 0; i < Len; i++)
      {
        pBytes[i] = ((pBytes2[i] & MASKINV) + (pBytes[i] & MASKINV)) ^ ((pBytes[i] ^ pBytes2[i]) & MASK);
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Does altering content of `bytes2` really necessary for your algorithm?

Comment: @PetSerAl, if the 8th bit of byte2 were not set to 0 there would be the possibility of overflow into the low bit of the next byte due to the carry. Thank you, the logic is necessary, the assignments were not. 25 ms -> 12 ms.  The new code is a little hard to read.

Comment: @Strom Is there any way to keep overflown value, so I can calculate the average if needed.

Comment: @Strom what if we convert byte[] to short[] and after sum convert it back to byte[]. How would the MASK/MASKINV change ?

Comment: @Pavel, The masks for ushort values are 0x8000800080008000, and the inverse 0x7fff7fff7fff7fff, 1. this would lose half of the efficiency. 2. the mask would be unneeded(if the highest 1 is less than the 15th bit for each operand).