# Summing N arrays of bytes efficiently

Tags: c#, arrays, bit-manipulation, byte

Below is the code to visualize what's need to be done. I am looking for a solution that can do it faster. One of them is to Sum to arrays using bit manipulation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55945544/4791668). I wonder if there is any way to do it the way described in the link and find the average at the same time.

```
    var random = new Random();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[20_000_000]; 
    byte[] bytes2 = new byte[20_000_000];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = (byte)random.Next(255);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes2[i] = (byte)random.Next(255);
    }

    //how to optimize the part below
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = (byte)((bytes[i] + bytes2[i]) / 2);
    }
```

/////////// Solution that needs to be improved. It doesn't do the average part.

```
    var random = new Random();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[20_000_000]; 
    byte[] bytes2 = new byte[20_000_000];

    int Len = bytes.Length >> 3; // >>3 is the same as / 8

    ulong MASK =    0x8080808080808080;
    ulong MASKINV = 0x7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f;

    //Sanity check
    if((bytes.Length & 7) != 0) throw new Exception("bytes.Length is not a                 multiple of 8");
    if((bytes2.Length & 7) != 0) throw new Exception("bytes2.Length is not a multiple of 8");

    unsafe
    {
//Add 8 bytes at a time, taking into account overflow between bytes
       fixed (byte* pbBytes = &bytes[0])
       fixed (byte* pbBytes2 = &bytes2[0])
       {
          ulong* pBytes = (ulong*)pbBytes;
          ulong* pBytes2 = (ulong*)pbBytes2;
          for (int i = 0; i < Len; i++)
          {
            pBytes[i] = ((pBytes2[i] & MASKINV) + (pBytes[i] & MASKINV)) ^ ((pBytes[i] ^ pBytes2[i]) & MASK);
          } 
       }        
    }
```

Comment: `I am looking for a solution that can do it faster`, so does your code work? If so it's best over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, it should now. Thank you.

Comment: How does your unsafe code handle the `/2`?

Comment: @NetMage it doesn't. That's exactly what I'm trying to ask if it can be done through this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Using bit manipulation, you can compute the average of the bytes in parallel:

```
ulong NOLOW = 0xfefefefefefefefe;
unsafe {
    //Add 8 bytes at a time, taking into account overflow between bytes
    fixed (byte* pbBytes = &bytes[0])
    fixed (byte* pbBytes2 = &bytes2[0])
    fixed (byte* pbAns2 = &ans2[0]) {
        ulong* pBytes = (ulong*)pbBytes;
        ulong* pBytes2 = (ulong*)pbBytes2;
        ulong* pAns2 = (ulong*)pbAns2;
        for (int i = 0; i < Len; i++) {
            pAns2[i] = (pBytes2[i] & pBytes[i]) + (((pBytes[i] ^ pBytes2[i]) & NOLOW) >> 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I modified the code to store in a separate `ans` byte array since I needed the source arrays to compare the two methods. Obviously you could store back to the original `bytes[]` if desired.

This is based on this formula: `x+y == (x&y)+(x|y) == (x&y)*2 + (x^y) == (x&y)<<1 + (x^y)`, which means you can compute `(x+y)/2 == (x&y)+((x^y) >> 1)`. Since we know we are computing 8 bytes at a time, we can mask the low order bit out of every byte so we shift in a 0 bit for the high order bit of every byte when we shift all 8 bytes.

On my PC this runs 2x to 3x faster (trending to 2x for longer arrays) than the (byte) sum.